# CSS preserve space to next line

Tags: html, css

[image]

[image]

I'm writing a text on fixed width div.
In the image, you can see there's no space on the first line, but whitespace is not rendered on the next line. It is gone!

I tried setting white-space: pre, pre-wrap, pre-line, but didn't work. Changing space to &nbsp also doesn't work since it is longer than normal space and doesn't wrap.

1. Is there any way to add space to the start of the next line? Text dynamically changes so splitting to separate div and adding margin/padding is hard. If it is impossible, what would be a good way to do this? Currently, I'm thinking of measuring width and split at appropriate position.
   Example first picture goal):
   `Hello this is not working help me stackover1`
    `thank you` <- space at start
2. Is it possible to break line at any letter, not space? For example in second picture, it should print like this:
   `Hello this is not working help me stackover1`
   `2 thank you`

Sorry my question is hard to understand.

Comment: Please provide a code sample which reproduces/demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Try using `word-wrap: break-all` unless I misunderstood something that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to `String.replace()` all spaces with `&nbsp;`. This will force spaces to render, even on a line break.

```js
let lines = document.querySelectorAll(".line");
lines.forEach(line => {
  line.innerHTML  = line.innerHTML.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");
});
```

```css
.line{
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  width:290px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">Hello this is not working help me stackover1
 thank you</div>

<div class="line">Hello this is not working help me stackover1
2 thank you</div>
```